# How could I check no used i18n translations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

After developing a period time, I found I have hundreds of i18n translated strings in i18n YAML files.

Is there any tool to check no used translations so that I can remove them from the YAML files.

On of the way to find them all is to use GREP command, but it's sort of time-consuming job.

Any good solution ?